# Replacing regex characters with their literal in Google BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a many Bigquery tables that contain passwords. I am trying to find reuse between passwords. For example, I want to be able to find when passwords are an extension of another

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|    Password From    |   Password From  |
|       Table 1       |     Table 2      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      computer       |    computer77    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

To do this I join my tables and then use the function [REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, regex)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains) where I would specify a `WHERE` and have `REGEXP_CONTAINS(Table1.password, Table2.password)` The overall query would go something like this (my passwords are stored as `BYTES`):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT safe_cast(A.password as STRING) as Astr, safe_cast(B.password as STRING) as Bstr
FROM Passwords.table1 as A
INNER JOIN Passwords.table2 as B
USING (email)
WHERE A.password != B.password)
WHERE (REGEXP_CONTAINS(Astr, Bstr) OR 
       REGEXP_CONTAINS(Bstr, Astr))
```

The problem with such an approach is that my password field contain characters that are not escaped when interpreted as a regular expression. It gives me an error like:

```
Cannot parse regular expression: no argument for repetition operator: ?
```

My first approach is to simply remove all the characters that are problematic with:

```
regexp_replace(Astr, r'[~\[\]?\(\)*\\+]', '')
```

This solves the problem in most cases but will change the actual number of matches when passwords contain such characters. Either it will make two passwords match when they should not or it will remove matches that should be present.

My next solution is trying to escape all these characters with the same `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. I test the replacement with a query like so:

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(A.password as STRING), 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(SAFE_CAST(A.password as STRING), r'[\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]]', 'AAAAAAAAAAAAA\\0')
FROM Passwords.yahoo as A
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(SAFE_CAST(A.password as STRING), r'[\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]]')
```

Now this almost does what I want where field goes from `test$` to `testAAAAAAAAAAAAA$`

Now if I switch the replacement from `AAAAAAAAAAAAA\\0` to `\\\\0` it changes `test$` to `test\0`. I want to end up with `test$` becoming `test\$`.

How can I add a `\` before all `.*+?^${}[]()` characters using the REGEXP_REPLACE function.

Examples:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Original       |   Transformed    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      test$pp^       |    test\$pp\^    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      pa$$word1      |    pa\$\$word1   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ^^(..)^^       | \^\^\(\.\.\)\^\^ |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

In the end I would like to be able to use this REGEXP_REPLACE to perform queries of reuse without getting errors. Example:

```
select *
from(
select A.password, B.password as Bpass, safe_cast(A.password as string) as Astr, safe_cast(B.password as string) as Bstr
from Passwords.Table1 as A
inner join Passwords.Table2  as B
using (email)
where A.password != B.password)
where REGEXP_CONTAINS(Bstr, regexp_replace(Astr, r'[\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]]', !REPLACEMENT!)) or REGEXP_CONTAINS(Astr, regexp_replace(Bstr, r'[~\[\]?\(\)*\\+]', !REPLACEMENT!))
```

Comment: can you provide some sample of input data and expected result

Comment: Added 1 example, can provide more

Comment: so do you consider second one being extension of first one? what would be definition of such extension - `passwords are an extension of another` ? yes, few more example would also help to understand what is in your mind :o)

Comment: I want to be able to use my passwords as a regex to match passwords in another table, without getting errors. To do so I need to escape all the characters that cause the password to be considered an invalid regex

Comment: without clear example of input data and expected output - it will be hard to help you. someone might be able though, but i recommend you to add it in your question - not just intermediate stuff - but very input and expected output

Comment: I did provide an example of input output, but i can't post actual data since these are real passwords leaked online. I will provide more examples in the last table

Comment: sorry, i still don't get it - someone else might be able to jump in

Comment: @PhilippeFisher, could you explain the reason why you use REGEXP_CONTAINS over STRPOS? You are just looking for substring right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `\\\\\\0`

We can use the matching string in replacement using '\0'. Add '\' before it. With escape characters, the overall replacement will look like '**`\\\\\\0`**'

```
regexp_replace(Astr, r'[\.\*\+\?\^\$\{\}\(\)\|\[\]]', '\\\\\\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar kind of Problem where

Table A contains the value "computer77"
Table B Contains the pattern "computer(\d{2})"

I try to join both the table using  REGEXP_CONTAINS but getting the error "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid escape sequence: \d"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post should be an answer to the question and not a question itself. So ask a new question. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34081629)